# Convenient use of Android XmlResourceParser?

Tags: android, scala, xml-parsing, android-resources, simple-framework

When I need to access a compiled Android XML resources, it seems that I cannot use `openRawResource(resId)` since it gives me a compiled binary.

The only way I've found to get the XML is to use `getXml(resId)` that returns `XmlResourceParser` (which implements `XmlPullParser`).

How can I conveniently deserialize complex compiled XMLs (but not big) from Android resources?

I have tried to hack the [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) XML framework:

```
val serializer = new Persister()
serializer.read(classOf[AFoo], 
    new NodeReader(new PullReader(r.getXml(resId))).readRoot)
```

(The Scala code above is simplified.)

However it fails:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: getPrefix not supported
    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPrefix(XmlBlock.java:156)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader$Start.<init>(PullReader.java:373)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.start(PullReader.java:143)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.read(PullReader.java:109)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.read(PullReader.java:117)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.next(PullReader.java:89)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readElement(NodeReader.java:111)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readRoot(NodeReader.java:85)
```

- Is there any XML deserializer that does not call `getPrefix`?
- Or is there already existing Scala library that builds a `Node` tree from the `XmlPullParser`? (So it will be possible to query it using the Scala projection function.)
- Or do you have any other hint how to read small but complex compiled XMLs from resources?

Comment: Instead of storing xml files in res/xml -- have you tried storing them in res/raw?   That is how I store xml documents which I want to have direct access to.

The wrinkle to saving schemas/stylesheets is that the extension needs to be 'xml' - what I do is prepend actual extension to the file name.... so indent.xsl becomes xsl_indent.xml

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the version of XmlPull you are using does not support namespaces. Try use the

org.simpleframework.xml.stream.DocumentProvider

This uses w3c DOM.

Comment: `DocumentProvider` does not support the `XmlPullReader` as a source. Or how you are using it with `XmlResourceParser`?

Answer (score 0):

I made a wrapper class and finally got around the issue. (I'm using Java instead of Scala.)

```
Persister serializer = new Persister();
serializer.read(AFoo.class, 
    new NodeReader(new PullReader(new XmlPullParserWrapper(r.getXml(resId)))).readRoot())
```

where

```
public class XmlPullParserWrapper implements XmlPullParser {
    private XmlPullParser mParser;

    public XmlPullParserWrapper(XmlPullParser parser) {
        mParser = parser;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFeature(String name, boolean state) throws XmlPullParserException {
        mParser.setFeature(name, state);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getFeature(String name) {
        return mParser.getFeature(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(String name, Object value) throws XmlPullParserException {
        mParser.setProperty(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        return mParser.getProperty(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInput(Reader in) throws XmlPullParserException {
        mParser.setInput(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInput(InputStream inputStream, String inputEncoding) throws XmlPullParserException {
        mParser.setInput(inputStream, inputEncoding);
    }

    @Override
    public String getInputEncoding() {
        return mParser.getInputEncoding();
    }

    @Override
    public void defineEntityReplacementText(String entityName, String replacementText) throws XmlPullParserException {
        mParser.defineEntityReplacementText(entityName, replacementText);
    }

    @Override
    public int getNamespaceCount(int depth) throws XmlPullParserException {
        return mParser.getNamespaceCount(depth);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespacePrefix(int pos) throws XmlPullParserException {
        return mParser.getNamespacePrefix(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceUri(int pos) throws XmlPullParserException {
        return mParser.getNamespaceUri(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespace(String prefix) {
        return mParser.getNamespace(prefix);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDepth() {
        return mParser.getDepth();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPositionDescription() {
        return mParser.getPositionDescription();
    }

    @Override
    public int getLineNumber() {
        return mParser.getLineNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnNumber() {
        return mParser.getColumnNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWhitespace() throws XmlPullParserException {
        return mParser.isWhitespace();
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return mParser.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getTextCharacters(int[] holderForStartAndLength) {
        return mParser.getTextCharacters(holderForStartAndLength);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return mParser.getNamespace();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return mParser.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmptyElementTag() throws XmlPullParserException {
        return mParser.isEmptyElementTag();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttributeCount() {
        return mParser.getAttributeCount();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeNamespace(int index) {
        return mParser.getAttributeNamespace(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeName(int index) {
        return mParser.getAttributeName(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributePrefix(int index) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeType(int index) {
        return mParser.getAttributeType(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAttributeDefault(int index) {
        return mParser.isAttributeDefault(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeValue(int index) {
        return mParser.getAttributeValue(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeValue(String namespace, String name) {
        return mParser.getAttributeValue(namespace, name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getEventType() throws XmlPullParserException {
        return mParser.getEventType();
    }

    @Override
    public int next() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        return mParser.next();
    }

    @Override
    public int nextToken() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        return mParser.nextToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void require(int type, String namespace, String name) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        mParser.require(type, namespace, name);
    }

    @Override
    public String nextText() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        return mParser.nextText();
    }

    @Override
    public int nextTag() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        return mParser.nextTag();
    }
}
```